# Three columned rows with aligned center column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I achieve the following using Bootstrap 4?

```
+------------------------+----+-------+
|<short value>           | to | <....>|
+------------------------+----+-------+
|<this is a longer value>| to | <....>|
+------------------------+----+-------+
|<....>                  | to | <....>|
+------------------------+----+-------+
```

There can be one or more rows.
The center cell is the text "to".
The other cells are the start and end values, each of which may be very short or very long.

I need the center column to be vertically aligned throughout all rows. I tried this but did not get the desired result:

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col">...</col>
     <div class="col-auto">to</col>
     <div class="col">...</col>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col">...</col>
     <div class="col-auto">to</col>
     <div class="col">...</col>
 </div>
```

Comment: If you do this: `<div class="row"><div class="col-5">...</col><div class="col-2">to</col><div class="col-5">...</col></div>` for every row, all will be keep vertically aligned. If you use Boostrap 3, then use `col-xs-5`, `col-xs-2`. Maybe with a little more of context (perhaps a snippet example) I can be more helpful to you.

Comment: @D.Smania that would mean the columns will collapse on smaller screens nvm. i reverted to use a table. :)

Comment: Yea, columns are responsive, they will have less width on smallest screens, if that is what you mean.